# How to set user name in session and get the user name in other view methods

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates, session-cookies

I'm new to Python and Django.
I'm using PHP form for login mechanism and once the login is successful, I'm sending the user name to Django application to carry on with other operations but I'm stuck in finding a best way to store the user name in session so that it can be used in other view methods

Below are some of my tries which failed:

1) Storing the user name in a global variable and access throughout the application but when another user login from their machine, user name gets changed in my machine.

2) Storing the user name in Django DB session but another user logs in with different user, it's showing the old user only.

3) I tried storing in the cache but still, it's not working.

DB session handler: It works fine when I access in sessionHandler method but it throws key error when i try to access in login method.

```
def sessionHandler(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('uname')
    request.session['user'] = userName
    print("current logged in user: " + request.session['user'])
    return JsonResponse({'Response': 'success'})

def login(request):
    uname = request.session.get('user')
    UserName = {"Name": uname}
    return render(request, 'login/login.html', UserName)
```

My use case is that any user who logs in their own machine and with own user name and password should be saved in the session data. Please help me to move further with this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: How is the `sessionHandler` method called? Also, use **snake_case** to name python variables and methods and not **camelCase**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and im sorry about that naming convention. I will correct it right away. You mean from PHP how is it called?

Comment: You don't have to be sorry lol. What I mean to ask is, are you sure the method `sessionHandler` gets called? There must be some `route` that corresponds to that method. Also, try copy pasting the error (if possible) that you are getting.

Comment: I'm sure that my PHP is calling the Django method and userName is getting passed to Django method successfully( Confirmed by printing the value inside sessionHandler method)...I'm not seeing any error but the username is not getting changed when another user login with a different username

Comment: I think you need to show how the PHP is calling the Django. Is it passing on any of the headers/cookies from the original request?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Below code shows you how I'm calling Django method and passing the user name to Django method. I'm storing the username in session through sessionHandler method
                                $.ajax({
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        url: 'http://localhost/NewHandBook/sessionHandler',
                                        data: {
                                                'uname': $('#username').val()
                                        },

Comment: @PatrickArtner Django documentation says request.session['user'] = userName is the syntax to store any variable in the session. Please correct me if I'm missing anything.

Comment: But the problem is that you are calling a Django URL from inside your PHP code. So from the point of view of Django it is always the same session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Got it...Could you please help me with any idea if you have...I just need to store the user name in the cookie so that I can use it across by application.

Comment: If you use Django, I do not understand why do you want to keep user in session. 
When you use django.contrib.auth authenticate/login/logout, you store logged user inside request object. Did you try it?

Comment: @MarekGancarz but im not using Django based authentication, I'm using PHP for authentication and once authentication is successful, I'm passing user name to Django to store it in a session so that I can use it throughout my application